# VB.NET - Remove Item From Multi-Dimensional ArrayList By Query?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, linq, multidimensional-array

I am looking to remove an element from an ArrayList using a query, E.g.
DELETE FROM arraylist WHERE (0) = "User1"
(Where (0) is the index of the second dimension).

Code:

```
Dim Users As New ArrayList
Users.Add({"User0", "Details"})
Users.Add({"User1", "Details"})
Users.Remove("User1")
```

The reason I am looking for a query way to do this is because I will not know what the second dimension value will be.

Comment: Using a List(T) instead of an ArrayList would be better. ArrayList is not generic so you always have to do some casting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim Users As New ArrayList
Users.Add(new String(){"User0", "Details"})
Users.Add(new String(){"User1", "Details"})
Dim userToRemove = Users.Cast(Of String()).Where(Function(i) i(0).Equals("User1")).Single()

Users.Remove(userToRemove)
```